# Why doesn´t Mathematica solve the integral Integrate[Sqrt[a^2*(Sin[x])^2+1],{x,0,2*Pi}]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have to solve that integral and I am sure it is good written. It is an elliptical integral but Mathematica just doesn´t solve it. What is the result to that integral?

```
Integrate[Sqrt[a^2*(Sin[x])^2 + 1], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: It works if you add `Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes when Mathematica can not solve the definite integral:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[a^2*(Sin[x])^2 + 1], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then a workaround can be sometimes, is to find the indefinite integral and then applying Fundamental theorem of calculus works. This is the case here

```
r = Integrate[Sqrt[a^2*(Sin[x])^2 + 1], x];
Limit[r, x -> 2 Pi] - Limit[r, x -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Assuming `a` real, also makes the definite integral work

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals],Integrate[Sqrt[a^2*(Sin[x])^2 + 1], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]